# Send byte[] of image from Spring Controller to jQuery

Tags: java, jquery, spring, image, byte

Tell me please right way how I can get image from Spring Controller and show its image on html? Now I'm trying like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "dictionaries/getImage", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public byte[] getImage(@RequestParam Long ticketTemplateId, @RequestParam String imageName) throws IOException{
    Long eventOrganizerId = eventOrganizerService.getCurrentUserOrganizerProfile().getId();
    byte[] result = fileStorageService.getImage(ticketTemplateId, eventOrganizerId, imageName);

    return result;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
function downloadImage() {
            var imageName = $('#slc option:selected').val();
            var ticketTemplateId = getParameterByName('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'getImage',
                type: 'GET',
                data: ({ticketTemplateId: ticketTemplateId, imageName: imageName}),
                success: function(data) {
                    document.getElementById("ItemPreview").src = "data:image/png;base64," + data;
                }
            })
        }
```

In browser console I get this error:

```
 data:image/png;base64,%EF%BF%BDPNG%1A%00%00%00IHDR%00%00%00%EF%BF%BD%00%00%…%EF%BF%BD5%EF%BF%BD0%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%00%00%00%00IEND%EF%BF%BDB`%EF%BF%BD net::ERR_INVALID_URL
```

Comment: Try changing `produces` to `MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE`.

Comment: @shmosel unfortunately I have same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot send raw bytes using ajax, it will try to interpret them as a Utf-16 string.

You can encode those bytes using Base64 on the sever and then set the `src` property directly with the encoded string, exactly with the js code that you are using.

On the java side you need only `return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(result)`